# Java spring framework - how to set content type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring action that I am rendering some json from the controller, at the minute its returning the content type 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1'.

How can I change this to be 'application/json'?

Comment: See also this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11349642/66686

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass the `HttpServletResponse` to your action method and set the content type there:

```
public String yourAction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that put I just get the error "cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse" when compiling

Comment: well, did you import it? `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServeltResponse`

Comment: and do you have the servlet-api on your classpath

Answer (score 5):

Did you try using the [MappingJacksonJsonView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html)?

> Spring-MVC View that renders JSON content by serializing the model for the current request using Jackson's ObjectMapper.

It sets the content-type to: `application/json`.

Comment: Heh, I was doing manually what has already been provided for me by Spring. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "jsonDemoDude", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCssForElasticSearchConfiguration(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {        
        String jsonContent= ...;
        HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);
        wrapper.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        wrapper.setHeader("Content-length", "" + jsonContent.getBytes().length);
        response.getWriter().print(jsonContent);
}
```

You can also add the aditional X bytes or whatever for "callback" part in case you want [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) ( cross site json request ) .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but this only works if one is grabbing the HttpServletResponse in the controller.

In Spring 3 we're being encouraged to avoid references to anything in the servlet domain, keeping things solely to our POJOs and annotations. Is there a way to do this without referencing the HttpServletResponse? I.e., keeping ourselves *pure*?

Comment: You could use a JSR-311 (JAX-RS) implementation, that provides explicit control of content types via annotations. Here is a discussion of those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey

Comment: Yes, you can use the "produces" attribute of the @RequestMapping annotation, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12023805/10433 for an example of setting the encoding this way.