# Who sets response content-type in Spring MVC (@ResponseBody)

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm having in my Annotation driven Spring MVC Java web application runned on jetty web server (currently in maven jetty plugin).

I'm trying to do some AJAX support with one controller method returning just String help text. Resources are in UTF-8 encoding and so is the string, but my response from server comes with

```
content-encoding: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

even when my browser sends

```
Accept-Charset  windows-1250,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
```

I'm using somehow default configuration of spring

I have found a hint to add this bean to the configuration, but I think it's just not used, because it says it does not support the encoding and a default one is used instead.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

My controller code is (note that this change of response type is not working for me):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/gethelp")
public @ResponseBody String handleGetHelp(Locale loc, String code, HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.debug("Getting help for code: " + code);
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    String help = messageSource.getMessage(code, null, loc);
    log.debug("Help is: " + help);
    return help;
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Simple declaration of the `StringHttpMessageConverter` bean is not enough, you need to inject it into `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`:

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, using this method you have to redefine all `HttpMessageConverter`s, and also it doesn't work with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

So, perhaps the most convenient but ugly method is to intercept instantiation of the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` with `BeanPostProcessor`:

```
public class EncodingPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name)
            throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter) {
            HttpMessageConverter<?>[] convs = ((AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter) bean).getMessageConverters();
            for (HttpMessageConverter<?> conv: convs) {
                if (conv instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                    ((StringHttpMessageConverter) conv).setSupportedMediaTypes(
                        Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "html", 
                            Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
                }
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

-

```
<bean class = "EncodingPostProcessor " />
```

Comment: It seem like a dirty hack. I don't like it but to use. Spring framework developers should work on this case!

Comment: Where does the line <bean class = "EncodingPostProcessor " /> go?

Comment: @zod: In `DispatcherServlet`'s config (`...-servlet.xml`)

Comment: Thanks.  It appears to be ignored.  We are using mvc (I think) and we have a class with a @Controller attribute, that appears to be the entry point.  The class is not mentioned anywhere else (it has an interface with a similar name) yet it is instantiated and called correctly.  Paths are mapped with a @RequestMapping attribute.  We are unable to control the content type of the response (we need xml).  As you can probably tell, I have no idea what I am doing, and the developer who created this has left my company.  Thanks.

Comment: As @digz6666 says this is a dirty hack. Spring should see how JAX-RS does it.

Comment: Creators of Spring MVC don't know which encoding is the most popular?!

Answer (score 179):

I found solution for Spring 3.1. with using @ResponseBody annotation.
Here is example of controller  using Json output:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDealers", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public String sendMobileData() {

}
```

Comment: +1. This solved it for me too, but only after I switched to using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in applicationContext. (Instead of `<bean class=" [...] DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>`, which is deprecated in Spring 3.2 anyway...)

Comment: ca this produce application/xml if annotated this way?

Comment: @Hurda: Obviously you can specify any content type that you wish by changing the value of the `produces` attribute.

Comment: There is a MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, for "application/json" as well.

Comment: +1 because it works, but a more general solution allowing you to specify the encoding in one place only instead of replicating it on every controller could be better.

Comment: What happens if you pass an array of content types  - `produces = {"some type", "another type"}`

Comment: It works after adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in applicationContext.xml.

Comment: For UTF-8, see `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`.

Answer (score 52):

Note that in Spring MVC 3.1 you can use the MVC namespace to configure message converters:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Or code-based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", UTF8)));
    converters.add(stringConverter);

    // Add other converters ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sort of works, except that 1) it pollutes the response with an `Accept-Charset` header that probably lists every known character encoding, and 2) [when the request has an `Accept` header the `supportedMediaTypes` property of the converter is not used](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/108536-responsebody-reports-utf-8-charset-in-http-response-but-uses-actually-iso-8859-1-ha), so for example when I make the request typing directly the URL in a browser the response has a `Content-Type: text/html` header instead.

Comment: You can simplify as "text/plain" is default anyway: 
`<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"><constructor-arg value="UTF-8" /></bean>`

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right answer. Also, @IgorMukhin 's way to define StringHttpMessageConverter bean works. This answer is used to set response content-types for all servlets. If you just need to set reponse content type for a particular controller method, use Warrior 's answer instead( use produces argument in @RequestMapping)

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli your first question can be solved by add <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false" /> to the bean

Answer (score 46):

Just in case you can also set encoding by the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/gethelp")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleGetHelp(Locale loc, String code, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    log.debug("Getting help for code: " + code);
    String help = messageSource.getMessage(code, null, loc);
    log.debug("Help is: " + help);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("returning: " + help, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I think using StringHttpMessageConverter is better than this.

Comment: This is also the solution if you get the error `the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.` in IE 11. Thanks digz!

Answer (score 20):

you can add produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" to RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/create/document", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String create(Document document, HttpServletRespone respone) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    
    Document newDocument = DocumentService.create(Document);
    
    return jsonSerializer.serialize(newDocument);
}
```

Comment: It is a incorrect answer. As per spring docs:

The producible media types of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

The format is a sequence of media types ("text/plain", "application/*), with a request only mapped if the Accept matches one of these media types. Expressions can be negated by using the "!" operator, as in "!text/plain", which matches all requests with a Accept other than "text/plain".

Answer (score 11):

I was fighting this issue recently and found a much better answer available in Spring 3.1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/gethelp", produces = "text/plain")
```

So, as easy as JAX-RS just like all the comments indicated it could/should be.

Comment: Worth porting to Spring 3.1 for!

Comment: @dbyoung That doesn't seem right, the javadoc for the `produces` says: "...request only mapped if the Content-Type matches one of these media types." which means AFAIK that the `produces` is relevant to whether the method matches a request and not how which content-type the response should have.

Comment: @Ittai correct! "produces" determines if the method matches the request, but NOT what content type is in the response. something else must be looking at "produces" when determining what content type to set

Answer (score 6):

You can use produces to indicate the type of the response you are sending from the controller. This "produces" keyword will be most useful in ajax request and was very helpful in my project

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aURLMapping.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8") 

public @ResponseBody String getMobileData() {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks digz6666, your solution works for me with a slight changes because I'm using json:

```
responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

The answer given by axtavt (whch you've recommended) wont work for me. Even if I've added the correct media type:

```
if (conv instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {                   
                    ((StringHttpMessageConverter) conv).setSupportedMediaTypes(
                        Arrays.asList(
                                new MediaType("text", "html", Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
                                new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8")) ));
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

I set the content-type in the MarshallingView in the [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html) bean. It works easily, clean and smoothly:

```
<property name="defaultViews">
  <list>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
      <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />     
      </constructor-arg>
      <property name="contentType" value="application/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
    </bean>
  </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the CharacterEncodingFilter, configured in web.xml. Maybe that helps.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: This just filters character in request, not in response - I'm allready using this one

Comment: @Hurda: With `forceEncoding=true` it filters the response too, but it wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: Best and quicker answer so far. I also was already declaring and using this filter, but with ```forceEncoding=false```. I just set it to ```false``` and "charset=UTF-8" is successfully added to ```Content-Type``` header.

Answer (score 2):

if none of the above worked for you try to make ajax requests on "POST" not "GET" , that worked for me nicely ... none of the above did. I also have the characterEncodingFilter.

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.your.package.spring.fix;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * @author Szilard_Jakab (JaKi)
 * Workaround for Spring 3 @ResponseBody issue - get incorrectly 
   encoded parameters     from the URL (in example @ JSON response)
 * Tested @ Spring 3.0.4
 */
public class RepairWrongUrlParamEncoding {
    private static String restoredParamToOriginal;

    /**
    * @param wrongUrlParam
    * @return Repaired url param (UTF-8 encoded)
    * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    */
    public static String repair(String wrongUrlParam) throws 
                                            UnsupportedEncodingException {
    /* First step: encode the incorrectly converted UTF-8 strings back to 
                  the original URL format
    */
    restoredParamToOriginal = URLEncoder.encode(wrongUrlParam, "ISO-8859-1");

    /* Second step: decode to UTF-8 again from the original one
    */
    return URLDecoder.decode(restoredParamToOriginal, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

After I have tried lot of workaround for this issue.. I thought this out and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to solve this problem in Spring 3.1.1 is that: add following configuration codes in `servlet-context.xml`

```
    <annotation-driven>
    <message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes">    
    <beans:value>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    </message-converters>
    </annotation-driven>
```

Don't need to override or implement anything.

Answer (score 2):

if you decide to fix this problem through the following configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

you should confirm that there should only one mvc:annotation-driven tag in all your *.xml file.
otherwise, the configuration may not be effective.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding) " If a character encoding is not specified, the Servlet specification requires that an encoding of ISO-8859-1 is used ".If you are using spring 3.1 or later use the fallowing configuration to set charset=UTF-8 to response body
***@RequestMapping(value = "your mapping  url", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")***

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class ConfigurableStringHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<String> {

    private Charset defaultCharset;

    public Charset getDefaultCharset() {
        return defaultCharset;
    }

    private final List<Charset> availableCharsets;

    private boolean writeAcceptCharset = true;

    public ConfigurableStringHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("text", "plain", StringHttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET), MediaType.ALL);
        defaultCharset = StringHttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET;
        this.availableCharsets = new ArrayList<Charset>(Charset.availableCharsets().values());
    }

    public ConfigurableStringHttpMessageConverter(String charsetName) {
        super(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName(charsetName)), MediaType.ALL);
        defaultCharset = Charset.forName(charsetName);
        this.availableCharsets = new ArrayList<Charset>(Charset.availableCharsets().values());
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the {@code Accept-Charset} should be written to any outgoing request.
     * <p>Default is {@code true}.
     */
    public void setWriteAcceptCharset(boolean writeAcceptCharset) {
        this.writeAcceptCharset = writeAcceptCharset;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return String.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected String readInternal(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        Charset charset = getContentTypeCharset(inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody(), charset));
    }

    @Override
    protected Long getContentLength(String s, MediaType contentType) {
        Charset charset = getContentTypeCharset(contentType);
        try {
            return (long) s.getBytes(charset.name()).length;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            // should not occur
            throw new InternalError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(String s, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException {
        if (writeAcceptCharset) {
            outputMessage.getHeaders().setAcceptCharset(getAcceptedCharsets());
        }
        Charset charset = getContentTypeCharset(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        FileCopyUtils.copy(s, new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(), charset));
    }

    /**
     * Return the list of supported {@link Charset}.
     *
     * <p>By default, returns {@link Charset#availableCharsets()}. Can be overridden in subclasses.
     *
     * @return the list of accepted charsets
     */
    protected List<Charset> getAcceptedCharsets() {
        return this.availableCharsets;
    }

    private Charset getContentTypeCharset(MediaType contentType) {
        if (contentType != null && contentType.getCharSet() != null) {
            return contentType.getCharSet();
        }
        else {
            return defaultCharset;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample configuration :

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list>
                <bean class="ru.dz.mvk.util.ConfigurableStringHttpMessageConverter">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="UTF-8"/>
                </bean>
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```