# spring prefixjson with responsebody

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

when controller method return is @responsebody  , even if i put

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
     <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />   
</bean>
```

there will no && {} insert at the front of json data. anyone knows what is reason?

Comment: Declaring a `MappingJacksonJsonView` bean doesn't do anything. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON in `@RequestBody`/`@ResponseBody` is handled by `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` which is configured in `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.messageConverters`.

The easy way to configure it without interference with other features is to create a `BeanPostProcessor` to intercept creation of `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, see, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody/3617594#3617594).