# Spring JSON tainting response from JacksonMessageConverter

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, taint

I have a JacksonMessageConverter in my Spring application for returning JSON response.
But before the JSON is returned, I would like to taint the JSON as given in [Ajax Security - Preventing JSON hijacking](http://books.google.com/books?id=AIm_LV5a528C&pg=PT204&lpg=PT204&dq=json%20tainting&source=bl&ots=W2JbKZtaDk&sig=WRPejR2QHALjXOxkvanpwJRgT-E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sUZiT4GrMYnLtgfkhKCDCw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=json%20tainting&f=false). Is it possible to do so when using a message converter?

**Update**

Am looking for a solution similar to this [spring prefixjson with responsebody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440607/spring-prefixjson-with-responsebody) but I already have the configuration set up correctly. PFB

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But still the returned JSON is not prefixed with "&&{}".

NOTE : I would like to use a different prefix for the JSON as explained in [Ajax Security - Preventing JSON hijacking](http://books.google.com/books?id=AIm_LV5a528C&pg=PT204&lpg=PT204&dq=json%20tainting&source=bl&ots=W2JbKZtaDk&sig=WRPejR2QHALjXOxkvanpwJRgT-E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sUZiT4GrMYnLtgfkhKCDCw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=json%20tainting&f=false)
but even the default support provided in Jackson does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter to see, if `prefixJson` equals **true**.
If not, then your bean not injected propely.
If yes, look in the `writeInternal()` method of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter class. IT clearly do what you need:

```
try {
        if (this.prefixJson) {
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw("{} && ");
        }
        this.objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, o);
    }
```

If you want to add custom prefix, you need to override `writeInternal()` and do it there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am trying that approach currently. Will update the post with the answer once done.

Answer (score 1):

Easier approach would be to extend MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and override writeInternal method to do stuff like custom prefixing,etc