# Jackson JSON Prefixing

Tags: java, json, jackson, resteasy

I'm currently using RestEasy(2.3.6) with Jackson(1.9.9) and needing to prefix my JSON arrays with '{} &&' in order to prevent JSON hijacking.

I'm new to Jackson and am having a really hard time understanding where to insert anything like this.  I'm not even sure where to insert something like this to make it happen all the time, and I would like to take it one step further and be able to specify to only prefix return values that contain JSON arrays and not regular objects.

I imagine there is a class somewhere I need to subclass and override a method, and then register that class somehow.  Has anyone ever done anything like this?

Comment: Jackson 1.9.9??? The current version is 2.2.x... You should consider an upgrade!

Comment: Also: why is such hijacking of any concern to you? How do you generate your JSON currently?

Comment: 1.9.9 was pulled in with the dependency on resteasy-jackson-provider v2.3.6, so that's just what I went with.  Could probably set up exclusions and force it to use the newer one if there's something in there that will help solve my issue.  Whether or not to worry about hijacking is a decision that is not up to me.  Currently I'm using Jackson to automatically marshal pojos returned from my resteasy resource methods.

Comment: The point still remains, though: _why_ do you need to prevent "JSON hijacking"?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727096/spring-json-tainting-response-from-jacksonmessageconverter should help.

Answer (score 0):

Jukka, the question you linked to led me to a solution.  I extended `JacksonJsonProvider`, and overrode the `writeTo()` method.  There are a few conditions in there and I was able to add `jg.writeRaw("{}&&");` before each place it writes the value.  Also, since I'm using Spring, I had to annotate my class with `@Component` in order for it to be found.

Also another gotcha with creating your own `JsonProvider` subclass is your rest methods must have `@Produces('application/json')` (you should always be explicit with these anyway) or else the default `JsonProvider` will be used.