# How to get Unicode response to JSP in Spring MVC using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, unicode

I want to send a Unicode to JSP page using javascript. I went throug the internet but still could not find an answer. It always shows me something like '???? ????'. Can anybody tell me the answer please.

Here is my method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/conv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String add(@RequestParam(value = "input", required = true) String input) throws    UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String result = Run.getTranslation(input);
    log.info(result);
    byte[] bytesInUTF8 = result.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    String stringUsingUTF8 = new String(bytesInUTF8, "UTF-8"); 
    return stringUsingUTF8;
}
```

Here  is my JavaScript code (test.js)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
  var input = $("#in").val();
  $.ajax({  
             type : "POST",   
             url : "conv",   
             data : "input=" +input,  
             //contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
             success : function(response) {  
              $("#out").val(response)
             },  
             error : function(e) {  
              alert('Error msg: ' + e);   
             }  
        });  
    });
  $("#clear").click(function(){
  $("#out").val("");
  $("#in").val("");
  });
});
```

This is my JSP page

```
<Doctype html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
   <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/test.js"/>"></script>
<!-- You can add  resources to page like above, .css and .js should be in resources  folder  -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Translator</h1>
    <h4>Input</h4>
    <textarea id="in" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br>
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <textarea id="out" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <button id="clear"> Clear</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="submit"> Convert</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `encodeURIComponent` your values?

Comment: Still not. Could U tell me how to do that. Coz I am new in this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] bytesInUTF8 = result.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String stringUsingUTF8 = new String(bytesInUTF8, "UTF-8");
```

This takes the translated Unicode String, encodes it to bytes using the UTF-8 encoding, then decodes it back to a String using the same encoding. This is a round trip, `stringUsingUTF8` will always be exactly the same as `result`, so you can drop this.

```
return stringUsingUTF8;
```

Strings returned from Spring `@ResponseBody` methods get encoded for sending to the browser using the default encoding for Servlet. XMLHttpRequest expects UTF-8 by default, but because Servlet is old and horrible, that encoding is not UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1, which is almost never what you want.

To fix this you can set a custom `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. [About this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody)

Note that your input is also decoded using the Servlet default of ISO-8859-1. If you need to accept non-ASCII input as well as output you will need to set a `CharacterEncodingFilter` in your web.xml. [About this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685644/spring-mvc-characterencodingfilter-why-only-set-response-encoding-by-force) (Note multipart POST forms and GET forms have further complications. Character encoding in Servlet is really a very sad thing.)

```
data : "input=" +input,
```

This should be `encodeURIComponent(input)`, or just `data: {input: input}` to let jQuery take care of that for you. Otherwise characters like `&` and `%` will break.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should add this to your JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And here's some cool reading about this:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: It shows me error "The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request"

Comment: Do I have to change any configuration in Tomcat or somewhere else? This is my first time using Unicode in my applications.

Comment: The root cause of the Internal Error (HTTP 500) should be in your Tomcat's stdout/catalina.out log.