# ObjectMapper Not Handling UTF-8 Properly?

Tags: spring, character-encoding, jackson

I'm using ObjectMapper to serialize posts in my system to json. These posts contain entries from all over the world and contain utf-8 characters. The problem is that the ObjectMapper doesn't seem to be handling these characters properly. For example, the string "Musée d'Orsay" gets serialized as "Mus?©e d'Orsay".

Here's my code that's doing the serialization:

```
public static String toJson(List<Post> posts) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(out, posts);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new String(out.toByteArray());
    }
```

Interestingly, the exact same `List<Post> posts` gets serialized just fine when I return it via a request handler using @ResponseBody using the following configuration:

```
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(Feature.USE_ANNOTATIONS)
        .disable(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter c = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    c.setObjectMapper(m);
    converters.add(c);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it your controller method which returns String directly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody

Comment: I think you should update that question, as the problem is NOT in ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from conversions, how about simplifying the process to:

```
return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(posts);
```

which speeds up the process (no need to go from POJO to byte to array to decode to char to build String) as well as (more importantly) shortens code.

Comment: Perfect. So much simpler than what I was doing. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Not 10 minutes later and I found the problem. The issue wasn't with the ObjectMapper, it was with how I was turning the ByteArrayOutputStream into a string. I changed the code as follows and everything started working:

```
try {
        return out.toString("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return out.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Disregard this. While it works @StaxMan's answer is far better.