# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I searched a lot, but I didn't find a way to solve this problem below.

> Enviando POST para o GCM
>   Response Code: 400
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>       at br.com.farmas.util.Post2GCM.post(Post2GCM.java:46)
>       at br.com.farmas.main.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:17)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>       at br.com.farmas.util.Post2GCM.post(Post2GCM.java:43)
>       ... 1 more

could you help me please?

below, I show the code I am executing....

line 43 is the following: int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

```
Enviando POST para o GCM
Response Code: 400
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:      https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at br.com.farmas.util.Post2GCM.post(Post2GCM.java:46)
at br.com.farmas.main.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at br.com.farmas.util.Post2GCM.post(Post2GCM.java:43)
... 1 more
```

Below is the first code from where I do the call

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Enviando POST para o GCM");

    Post2GCM.post(API_KEY, criarContent());
}

private static Content criarContent() 
{
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Content content = new Content();
    content.addRegId("eCvEu9f2LFM:APA91bEB7AnrTxP1owl_QrFTLUc35vxs2rGOCpyajU5RTsuPY427IhFF8EayEC3WThQ54ag7q6mwbKUywohGvK_q-RTH0QlglJjVqzH9b9X-gx6Nli9_RJlLRnwyV10iervfexFB3fOy");
    content.addData("titulo", "Titulo Teste");
    content.addData("message", "Message Teste");
    content.addData("data", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    content.addData("id", "2");

    return content;
}
```

Below is the second code where the exception happens. The exception happens at the following line: int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

```
    public static void post(String apiKey, Content content) 
{
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        mapper.writeValue(outputStream, content);

        outputStream.flush();

        outputStream.close();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String linha = "";
        StringBuffer resultado = new StringBuffer();
        while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            resultado.append(linha);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        System.out.println(resultado);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you're making this call ?

Comment: 400 means a malformed request. which means something your sending isnt right.

Comment: can you try changing the content type to "application/json;charset=UTF-8" ?

Comment: @ShivV  I changed that line to connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); but the problem still happens.

Comment: Here are couple of posts which I think will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912990/objectmapper-not-handling-utf-8-properly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352133/server-side-gcm-returns-error-400?rq=1

Comment: @ShivV I checked your suggestions but I didn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you add the suggestions that you tried as an update to the post ?

Comment: @ShivV One of the things I tried was the whole post method of your first suggestion.

Comment: Your second suggestion is an older version of gcm and it doesn't sound good enough to be literally used because of it. But it post method sounds literally with mine.

Comment: @ShivV I didn't use a PROJECT_NUMBER as it mentions. I generated the google-services.json file. In Google Cloud Platform I have the server key and the android key. The android key is in google-services.json. The server key I use in API_KEY in the method Post2GCM.post(API_KEY, criarContent());

Comment: @ShivV I got the solution. Thank you for your patience and I'm sorry by my errors. I love these forum and I love your interest to help people.