# Spring 3.1 MVC - Getting character encoding error while using @ResponseBody annotation

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, character-encoding, response

I'm facing character encoding problem while using **@ResponseBody** annotation. If I use **response.getWriter().write()** method I have no problem which I can't see Turkish characters like ş,ö,ı, etc.. (*I see just question mark instead of them*)

I'm using **Spring's CharacterEncodingFilter** with **UTF-8 encoding**.

How can I resolve this problem? Do I have to change all my **@ResponseBody** annotation used methods to **response.getWriter().write()**?

**Sample Method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/isScdValid.ajax")
    public @ResponseBody String isScdValid(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        boolean isValid = true; // for sample
        // continues...
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("isValid", isValid);
        if(isValid) {
            jsonObj.put("username", scd.getUsername());
            jsonObj.put("sessionUserId", scd.getUserId());

        }
    return jsonObj.toString(); // not encoding with UTF-8
//        response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString()); // works right
    }
```

**Here's my character encoding filter:**

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Also added URIEncoding property to Tomcat:**

```
    <Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" 
redirectPort="9443"
URIEncoding="UTF-8" compression="on" 
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,text/json,text/css,text/plain,application/javascript,application/json,application/pdf"
/>
```

Comment: Show us some code from your java method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting encoding for the strings returned in the controller with @ResponseBody annotation is not a trivial task, I think you should see a similar question: [Who sets response content-type in Spring MVC (@ResponseBody)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody)

In Spring 3.1 configuration, you need to set up message converter as it was shown in [Rossen Stoyanchev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772620/241986) .