# EntityResponse charset encoding error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

In my REST API, I return a 404 whenever the user is trying to access a non existing resource.

However, Firefox does not display the "404 error" page, but complains about character encoding.

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/countries/{countryId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> country(@PathVariable Integer countryId) {
    return countriesService.getCountry(countryId);
}
```

which calls this method from the service entity:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getCountry(Integer countryId) {
    Country country = countryDAO.findById(countryId);
    if (country == null)
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new DetailedCountryJson(country));
}
```

DetailedCountryJson is a simple json object. So when I access

```
localhost:8080/countries/1
```

I get the json related to this country, but when I try with an id which is not in the database, I get

[image: the error displayed by firefox]

It says

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Comment: Can you translate the text in the image to English?

Comment: @RickS i added the translation into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use`response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");`
refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody)

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with annotations? I tried to add `produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` into the `@RequestMapping` but i get the same result

Comment: Ok it works now in the service entity, I just changed `ResponseEntity.notFound().header("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8").build()`. Thanks